# Examining AJAX HTTP requests using Web Inspector

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, web-inspector

Is there an easy way to examine the HTTP GET/POST/OPTIONS/HEAD etc requests being made by jquery ajax calls using WebKit's Web Inspector?  I'm hand crafting responses and am looking for a simple way to monitor the back and forth traffic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Resources tab will show Request/Response headers and the response itself. Were you looking for something else? Using "Sort by Start Time" is probably the most useful setting for watching new requests.

Comment: Oh yeah! It does. Just tried it on this page. I never noticed that before. Awesome.

Comment: I think a lot of folks underestimate Web Inspector - without taking anything away from Firebug, it's an impressive tool!

Comment: I use it. It's just that I don't pay attention as it gets updated. That's the crazy thing about Chrome. Updates happen silently.

Comment: How does one use "Sort by Start Time"? Don't see it anywhere.. (v6.0.4)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Firebug (a Firefox plugin) or a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ([here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) some example filters for Wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that WebInspector is designed to do what you are asking.

I use tcpTrace from PocketSoap.  I set my web browser up to use tcpTrace as a proxy.  It records all of the traffic going back and forth.  Its pretty slick.